# PHP MYSQL check if row data is the same as

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a little new to PHP and MYSQL. I'm creating an admin panel, in the MySQL database I have a column called `admin`.

I want it to check the column, So if `admin` has 0 on it, it will header to *index.php* but if it has 1 it will header to *admin.php*.

I would also like some help, For *admin.php* I want something like, if you were not on the database (checks if admin has 1 in the username), it will head somewhere else.

*Admin.php* code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if (isset($_SESSION['user']) != "") {
    header("Location: home.php");
}

if (isset($_POST['btn-login'])) {
    $uname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
    $admin = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['admin']);
    $upass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE admin = '1'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);

    if ($row['admin'] == 1) {
        header("Location: admin.php");
    }
    else {
        echo 'Shithead';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: If you are using SQL query like SELECT * FROM users WHERE admin='1' it will always give you the record with admin 1. What's your problem please elaborate it more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start you need to fetch the right row for the user.   You are fetching only rows that are admins !!!  Something like this.

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname='$uname' and pass='$pass'");
```

assuming that your db fields are called uname and pass.

You need to get this working and then ask a new question for the rest.